# selection and deselection in UICollectionView swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, uicollectionview, xcode7

I'm beginner in using Xcode7 and swift2. I used them to create collection view inside table cell.
I followed the tutorial in this link: https://www.thorntech.com/2015/08/want-your-swift-app-to-scroll-in-two-directions-like-netflix-heres-how/

Everything works fine, expect the selection when I selected one cell form the collection and scroll horizontally to select a different one the following happen:

1-the first selected one does not deselected.
2- the second one get selected, 
now I have two selected cells and the app crashed.

I want the user to select one cell only from the collection, so I used didselect, and deselect method, but still not working as expected.

Any guidance or resources to solve this issues are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For your collectionView set .allowsMultipleSelection to false

Comment: I think the problem is with scrolling.  If I select one cell and scroll (left or right) to see more I found another cell has been selected.  Any idea how to solve it ?